# 64bit shift problem

Tags: c++, 64-bit

Why this code does not write 0 as a last element but 18446744073709551615?
(compiled with g++)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    unsigned long long x = (unsigned long long) (-1);
    for(int i=0; i <= 64; i++)
        cout << i << " " << (x >> i) << endl;
    cout << (x >> 64) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know this is totally unrelated, but, never use "using namespace std;.  It's just an accident waiting to happen, hours spent chasing a bug that happened because you or a library just happens to have a method that matches the name of something in std.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you shift a value by more bits than word size, it **usually** gets shifted by `mod word-size`. Basically, shifting it by 64 means shifting by 0 bits which is equal to no shifting at all. You shouldn't rely on this though as it's not defined by the standard and it can be different on different architectures.

Comment: > shifting it by 64 means shifting by 0 bits which is equal to no shifting at all:


I've seen this said before, but I don't understand how this can be true for a shift operation.  Doesn't `val << 64 == val` actually describe a *rotate* operation?

`0xffff ffff ffff ffff << 64` should be 0, which is clearly different from not shifting at all.

Comment: @U007D You are correct that mathematically that's not true for a shift operation. I was describing what actually happens that often leads to the observed behavior in practice on x86 architecture (undefined by C): the CPU basically ignores the leftmost bits, which is equivalent to doing a mod 64 on the shift bit count, which is then equivalent to shifting by zero. I do not mean to imply the mathematical shift operation by 64 bits is equivalent to shift by 0.

Comment: Ah.  I had assumed that the mathematical and x86 results for << 64 would be the same since 0xffff ffff ffff ffff < 63 => 0x8000 0000 0000 0000 (ie. trending to all zeros).  But since << 64 is UB in C, what it *might* or *should* do if it were supported is pure speculation on my part.  @Mehrdad Afshari thank you for the clarification--I was genuinely puzzled! :)

Answer (score 10):

Shifting a number a number of bits that is equal to or larger than its width is undefined behavior. You can only safely shift a 64-bit integer between 0 and 63 positions.

Comment: this is wrong, the max amount of a right shift is 31, i.e. the shift amount is always masked by 0x1F internally. See intel manuals on SHR instruction.

Comment: @jn: Intel manuals define it for "x86 assembly." It's undefined at C level.

Comment: @Mehrdad: correct - i just checked the assembly output of MSVC compiled code. If the shift amount is greater than 32 the amount is masked with 0x1F, if the amount is greater than 64, the result of the shift is zero.

Answer (score 4):

This warning from the compiler should be a hint:

"warning: right shift count >= width of type"

This results in undefined behavior:

http://sourcefrog.net/weblog/software/languages/C/bitshift.html

Answer (score 1):

well, you are shifting one too many times. you are shifting from 0 to 64 inclusive which is a total of 65 times. You generally want:

```
for(int i=0; i < 64; i++)
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I get:

```
test.c:8: warning: right shift count >= width of type
```

so perhaps it's undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You overflow the shift. If you've noticed, GCC even warns you:

```
warning: right shift count >= width of type
```

How come? You include 64 as a valid shift, which is an undefined behavior.
counting from 0 to 64 there are 65 numbers (0 included). 0 being the first bit (much like arrays).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    unsigned long long x = (unsigned long long) (-1);
    for(int i=0; i < 64; i++)
        cout << i << " " << (x >> i) << endl;
    cout << (x >> 63) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Will produce the output you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
static inline pack_t lshift_fix64(pack_t shiftee, short_idx_t shifter){
  return (shiftee << shifter) & (-(shifter < 64));
}
```

for such a trick,

```
(-(shifter < 64)) == 0xffff ffff ffff ffff
```

if shifter < 64 and

```
(-(shifter < 64)) == 0x0
```

otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The bit pattern of -1 looks like 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in hex, for 64 bit types. Thus if you print it as an unsigned variable you will see the largest value an unsigned 64 bit variable can hold, i.e. 18446744073709551615.

When bit shifting we don't care what a value means in this case, i.e. it doesn't matter if the variable is signed or unsigned it is treated the same way (shifting all bits one step to the right in this case).

Comment: It does matter if the value is signed or not when you're right-shifting. Signed right shift fills the highest bits to the sign bit, unsigned right shift will fill them with 0. Effectively, right shift by "k" bits will have the same effect of dividing by 2^k.

Answer (score 0):

Another trap for the unwary: I know this is an old thread, but I came here looking for help. I got caught out on a 64 bit machine using 1<<k when I meant 1L<<k; no help from the compiler in this case :(