# Shifting 64 bit value left by 64 bits in C++ giving weird results

Tags: c++, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, shift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [64bit shift problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024968/64bit-shift-problem)

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 64-bit, targeting x64 in debug mode, using an AMD Phenom II.
So Basically...

```
uint64_t Foo = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF << 64;//Foo is now 0x0000000000000000
uint64_t Derp = 64;
uint64_t Bar = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF << Derp;//Foo is now 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Using a lower value such as 63 restores normal behavior.
Why is this happening and how can I get around it?

Update: I switched to release mode. Lo and behold, the issue vanished and both returned 0. But the issue remains in debug mode which is where I need to be in order to debug my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shift operation has undefined behavior if you shift by values greater than or equal to the bit width.

From Section 5.8 p1 in the C++11 draft:

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed.
>   The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. The behavior is undefined if the right operand
>   is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

Comment: why did they do it like that? Its the same in Java, makes no sense, it should set to zero if <<, or >>>, should max if >>

Comment: @gia The standard body typically decide to make the behavior undefined so that compiler implementors do not have to generate expensive (slow) code to deal with edge cases.

Comment: it could come on the chip or something, I mean in the end I have to do the checks anyway :P

Comment: @gia If the argument is a literal constant, no check would be necessary.

Comment: true, in my case its not literals, i just added the checks, code is unreadable

Answer (score 4):

I believe shifting by the size of the integer or larger is undefined in C++.

Your first example is being evaluated at compile time as it involves only constants. Your second example is computed at run-time by the processor.

You can split the shift into two parts:

```
uint64_t Bar = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF << (Derp / 2);
Bar <<= Derp - (Derp / 2);
```